# Can a commercial pilot fly under this situation? about private carriage

Tags: faa-regulations

scenario 1.
I'm a commercial pilot/flight instructor and employee of the flight school, who carries the flight school’s CEO and other staff on business trips, do you know what part of the regulations that fall under?

scenario 2.
If the CEO's office calls and asks you to pick up a donor and fly them to Newyork for a weekend of shopping,
is this part 91, 121, 135 or an exception under 119?

Comment: I'm going to pop some popcorn and watch this one...  ;)

Comment: #1 is company owned plane carrying company people on company business.  Sounds 91 unless there is more to it.  #2 is a charter.

Comment: Questions on this site are better focusing on 1 question each - otherwise you get a partial answers as has already been demonstrated. You may like to edit this to focus on q1 which has an answer, and repost q2 as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Both scenarios appear to be under 14 CFR Part 91. Scenario #1 is private carriage by virtue of being an employer owned aircraft flying employees, flown by an employee, for company business. Scenario #2 can get sticky. But, if the “donor” is not paying for the flight or compensating you or the owner/operator, it would still be Part 91. However, the “donations” would have to be justified.

Comment: #2 requires common purpose and hours are considered compensation.

Comment: @acpilot - The original question from Soartosky is about a person with a Commercial Pilot Certificate. Commercial and ATP pilots **can** be compensated under Part 91. In this case, the pilot would already be getting compensation from their employer, the owner/operator. The question would be whether the owner/operator can allow this operation under Part 91 considering the “donor” presumably has made contributions to some other part of the business not related to the flight department. For instance, is the donor the owner of a leaseback aircraft?

Comment: You're right.  I'm conditioned to read all of these as PPL questions.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1 would likely be private carriage according to the AC 120-12, because you're carrying a limited number of people from a defined group.
Number 2 we need more info. It either falls under charter/135 or fractional/91 or might be a contract if he is the only person you fly for.

Comment: He is the only person I fly for. and both #1 and #2 scenario use school's airplane.

Answer (score 0):

this is my think flow.

#1 scenario.

first, let's look at each person's role.

CEO is operational control of flight because we use CEO's aircraft.

- FAR says: operational control, with respect to a flight, means the exercise of authority over initiating, conducting or terminating a flight.

in addition, CEO is also not a commercial operator because business trip is merely incidental to other business and it is, in itself, not a major enterprise for profit.

So, CEO doesn't need a operating certificate.

I'm a hired pilot and have commercial certificate.

- FAR 61.133 says:

> **(a) Privileges** -
> **(1) General.** A person who holds a commercial pilot certificate may act as pilot in command of an aircraft -
> **(i)** Carrying persons or property for compensation or hire, provided the person is qualified in accordance with this part and with the applicable parts of this chapter that apply to the operation; and
> **(ii)** For compensation or hire, provided the person is qualified in accordance with this part and with the applicable parts of this chapter that apply to the operation.

So, I think it just exercise my commercial pilot privilege.

and If I have a instrument rating in same category, class and type and meet part 91 medical etc.

I think I can go and I will fly under part 91.

welcome any opinion about that answer :) and I will write for #2 scenario later.